# SQL Server checkpoints

Tags: sql-server, checkpoint

can anyone explain when SQL Server issues a checkpoint?

Answer (score 12):

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.asp

Events That Cause Checkpoints
Before a database backup, the Database Engine automatically performs a checkpoint so that all changes to the database pages are contained in the backup. In addition, checkpoints occur automatically when either of the following conditions occur:

- The active portion of the log exceeds
  the size that the server could
  recover in the amount of time
  specified in the recovery interval
  server configuration option.
- The log becomes 70 percent full, and
  the database is in log-truncate mode.
  A database is in log truncate mode
  when both these conditions are TRUE:
  the database is using the Simple
  recovery model, and, after execution
  of the last BACKUP DATABASE statement
  that referenced the database, one of
  the following events occurs:
- A minimally logged operation is
  performed in the database, such as a 
  minimally logged bulk copy operation 
  or a minimally logged WRITETEXT
  statement is executed. An ALTER
  DATABASE statement is executed that
  adds or deletes a file in the
  database.

Also, stopping a server issues a checkpoint in each database on the server. The following methods of stopping SQL Server perform checkpoints for each database:

Using SQL Server Configuration Manager.
Using SQL Server Management Studio.
Using the SHUTDOWN statement.